# how can i make my discord.js bot reply to one specific user?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord.js bot that will reply to one user when they type anything into the chat but I'm having trouble defining that user. Here is the code:

```
bot.on("message", message => {
if (message.content.includes(" ")) {
//the user im trying to target
if (!message.author.user(fuze_fatal1ty.user)) {
message.reply('No');
}
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worded poorly, but I think i get it, you would need to check to their id.

```js
bot.on("message", message => {
   if(msg.author.id === "THE_USER_ID") {
      msg.reply("No");
   }
});
```

Not sure what `fuze_fatal1ty.user` is supposed to be

Comment: thankyou so much I knew I was over complicating it that worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome, if it solved your problem you should accept the answer.

Comment: how do I do that sorry im new to this website

Comment: Looks like you found it, It's fine that you are new, you might want to read some articles by stackoverflow for newcomers.